# smart banner Flutter web app (IOS , Android )

Tags: android, ios, flutter, web

I need to display a smart banner in my Flutter web app and if the app is installed it shows "Open", otherwise it shows "View" which requires downloading. so I used this package "smart_banner 0.2.2" but when I open my web application in smart phone browser (IOS or Android) I have this error "an error has occurred". So how can I display this smart banner.

Comment: The question is not clear like this. It needs more specific information. What code are you running? Saying you installed a package is not sufficient. A suggestion could be to look for support on the specific package you mention, here: https://github.com/TesteurManiak/smart_banner/issues